# View with accumulated self referencing calculation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, recursion

I'm not even quite sure what to call what I am trying to do.  I need a column that accumulates the total of its own calculations on previous rows.  Here's a simplified example of the output I need (d is the column I need help with):

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   36  6   36  6
2   0   5   30  6
3   0   4   24  6
4   22  10  40  4
5   0   9   36  4
6   0   8   32  4
```

a is an autonumber column

b is user entered column

c is a column that usually counts down by one, but occasionally has other values added

d is equal to: the prior row of d + b - prior row of e

e is equal to d/c

It may help if I explain why I need this.  I'm working on simulating the impact of rate shocks on a banking institution (commonly called stress testing).  b is a column that represents some impact of an interest rate shock (example: a percentage change to the number of loans made).  c is a column that represents the number of months before the market is expected to return to normal without any further rate shocks.  d represents the impact on loans for that time period and e is the rate at which d is returning to zero.

Here is what I've tried so far and why it doesn't work:

```
SET var := 0;

SELECT var := var + b - var/c AS d
```

This would be my preferred solution, but I'm creating a view, and views are not allowed to reference user created variables.  It has to be a view because I need to reference it in other queries and views.

```
SELECT (lag(d,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY a)) + b - (lag(e,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY a)) AS d
```

This doesn't work because d hasn't been defined yet.  I just get an error that d isn't a column.

```
SELECT
     ((SELECT sum(temp.b)
     FROM table as temp
     WHERE temp.a <= a)
     /(SELECT sum(temp2.c)
     FROM table as temp2
     WHERE temp2.a = a))
```

This doesn't work because I need to divide the reduced value of d, not just the sum of b.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  It does not support window functions.

Comment: A running total?

Comment: This looks like a job for Excel, not SQL. Or a custom development.
How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: Only a small number of rows.  Maybe a few dozen at most.  However, this is one tiny piece of a larger project that doesn't play well with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is the cumulative sum of the difference between `b` and `c`.  This would be expressed as:

```
select a, b, c,
       sum(b - c) over (order by a) as d,
       d / sum(b - c) over (order by a) as e
from t;
```

I'm using window functions, even though the question is tagged MySQL.  MySQL only supports them since version 8.0.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately d is not the cumulative sum of the difference between b and c, so this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how stable the results would be in a VIEW, but you could use session variables.

```
SELECT a, b, c, @d := @d + b - @e AS d, @e := @d / c AS e
FROM t
   , (SELECT @d := 0 AS initD, @e := 0 AS initE) As init
ORDER BY a;
```

Also, keep in mind this is kind of crossing over into behavior observed, not actually guaranteed; as MySQL doesn't officially guarantee the select expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: Unfortunately i get "ERROR 1351: View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter".  It looks like I can't use session variables either.  :(

Comment: Unless it absolutely must be a VIEW, this query's results could still be put into a temporary table, or the query could possibly used as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with pure brute force.  I created a permanent table, and then I created a trigger which deletes all rows of the table and then recreates the table using the variable solution.  Thus any time the underlying data changes, MySQL automatically updates the table with the most current information.  The table acts like a view in that it is updated in real time, but is a permanent table.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't offer a FOR EVERY STATEMENT option for triggers, which means my code is running over and over again for every line that gets updated, so if I update 100 rows, my table gets deleted and recreated 100 times.

Still looking for a better solution, but at least this works.

Comment: You might be able to reduce the redundant work a little by only dropping and recreating the rows where `a >= NEW.a`; or if real-time is not absolutely required, you may be able to use an `EVENT` to recreate it on an interval.